# Any way to remove the duplicate SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, select-insert

For the sake of brevity, let's assume we have a `numbers` table with 2 columns: `id` & `number`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE numbers(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NUMBER INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

I want the `number` column to auto-increment, but restart from 1 after hitting 100, satisfying the following requirements:

1. If there are no records yet, set `number` to 1.
2. If there are already records in the table:

   1. If the last record's `number` is less than 100, set `number` to that + 1.
   2. If the last record's `number` is 100 or more, set `number` to 1.

Here's what I have so far:

```sql
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`number`)
VALUES (
    IF(
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT `number`
            FROM `numbers` as n
            ORDER BY `id` DESC
            LIMIT 1),
            0
        ) > 99,
        1,
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT `number`
            FROM `numbers` as n
            ORDER BY `id` DESC
            LIMIT 1),
            0
        ) + 1
    )
)
```

This works, but uses two identical `SELECT` queries.

Is there any way to remove the duplicate `SELECT`?

---

**P.S.** I want to do all this within a query. No triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: I gave a tentative answer, but I think you need to add `id` to your INSERT clause to make the question clearer.

Comment: @mdahlman - The `id` is obviously `AUTO-INCREMENT`ing.

Comment: Ahh. Then INSERT ... SELECT seems the standard solution to me. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use modulo `%` operator

```
INSERT INTO `numbers` (`number`)
VALUES (
          IFNULL(
            (SELECT `number`
            FROM `numbers` as n
            ORDER BY `id` DESC
            LIMIT 1),
            0
        ) % 100 + 1
    )
```

Comment: @JosephSilber   In this case `% 100`. [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28822). I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Exactly. BTW, what about race conditions? Is table locking (MyISAM) the only option here?

Comment: `If the last record's number is 100 or more, set number to 1.
`, `or more` will break the data. But anyway, if you insert data only with this query, then it's fine.

Comment: It should never be "or more" :) Are you saying that even if two of these queries run concurrently, I'll still always get consistent data? Is it not possible for the second query's SELECT to run after the first one's, but before the first query's INSERT runs?

Comment: @JosephSilber Never mind if you start with empty table. Your requirements said `If there are already records in the table` make the miss leading.

Comment: Not following you. Are addressing the race conditions, or the solution as a whole? 'cause the solution is rock solid; `IFNULL` will handle the case for when there are no records.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a temp variable.

```
INSERT INTO `numbers`(`number`) VALUES (
  IF((@a := IFNULL((SELECT number FROM `numbers` AS n ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) > 99, 1, @a + 1)
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@a :=` go before `IFNULL`? I don't want `@a` to be `null`!

Comment: It doesn't matter? Why??? Using the code you posted will insert `NULL` if there are no other records in the table!!

Comment: @JosephSilber Oh, sorry, that's true. Fixed it. Didn't consider the empty table.

Comment: You don't need the extra set of parentheses.

Comment: @JosephSilber It should be necessary for my test.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer, but I think using modulo is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I see. The modulo answer is nice. It feels 'brittle' to me as it would not handle the "100 or more" requirement as stated. It's fine if you change the requirement to "If the last record's number is exactly 100, set number to 1."

To me this is more intuitive:

```
INSERT INTO numbers (number)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN number >= 100 THEN 0
    ELSE COALESCE (number, 0)
  END + 1
FROM numbers
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How would this handle race conditions?

Comment: Why do you prefer `COALESCE` over `IFNULL`?

Comment: Just habit: Oracle users use NVL, MySQL users use IFNULL, but COALESCE has been part of standard SQL since 1992 so everyone supports it. Same result either way.

Comment: Race conditions should only depend on the isolation level. It should be the same as the modulo answer. Table locking should surely keep things consistent.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this great answer. Since "or more" was a mistake to be included on my part, I'll stick with the modulo answer.